# how to pause a loop for a number of seconds?

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement, sleep, pause

I'm trying to pause every time he has done 1 of the cases. But it doesn't matter where I put sleep(1), it will sleep 5 seconds and than give all the outputs at once. Or when im asking for 10 outputs it will wait 10 seconds before giving me the output.

What I want is to get a output with 1 second in between the next one, and so on. This is my code and I have made it as small as possible so it won't take forever to read.
I have tried to put sleep(1) on almost every spot but it all ended up the same.

```
//include list
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>


// variable list
int i = 0;
int StopNow;
int start = 0;


int main(void) 
{ 
    srand(time(0));

    while(i<5) 
    {
        switch(rand() % 4 + 1)      // picking a random number between 1 and 4.
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\n 1");
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("\n 2");
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("\n 3");
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("\n 4");
                break;
        }

        i++;
        sleep(1);               // Pause 
    }
}
```

Comment: from where did you run this program?

Comment: How do you run your program? In an online IDE?

Comment: See whether the behavior changes if you add `fflush(stdout);` call right before `sleep`. The output is probably being buffered.

Comment: @JulioAnthonyLeonard im running it in visual studio code

Comment: If you're using C++, use `cout` and `endl` to flush. If that doesn't help, try using `std::this_thread::sleep_for` instead of `Sleep`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to run your code on some online compiler
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

I assume nothing wrong with your code, maybe compiler issues.

If it still doesn't work, probably there is some issue with your buffer.

Sometimes, characters don't get print until some buffer exceeded or the newline gets printed. There are 2 way you can try this

1. Use the `fflush(stdout)` call before the `sleep` method to flush out the buffer
2. A better way to use C++ `cout` library as the library automatically flush for you

Comment: its not supposed to print stuff. just easier to test things. But thanks, the fflush(stdout) did the job

Comment: `cout` doesn't flush until it's buffer is full, same as `printf`. Unless you call the `flush` function, or use `endl` which causes a flush. Saying it is "automatic" is just as true (or false) as saying `printf` flushes automatically.